# Multiple form validation with same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am using form twice on same page.

HTML Code

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkwebform();">

<input id="codetext" maxlength="5" name="codetext" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter here" /> 

<input class="button" type="submit" value="SUMBIT" />
</form>
```

It's working fine with one form but when i add same form again then it stop working. The second form start **showing error popup alert but even i enter text in form field**.

JS Code

```
function checkwebform()
    {
    var codecheck = jQuery('#codetext').val();
    if(codecheck.length != 5)
    {
        alert('Invalid Entry');
    } else {
        showhidediv('div-info');
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can i make it to validate other forms on page using same function?

Comment: Can you post the html with both forms? you can't have elements with same `id` in the same document. Maybe you're calling `jQuery('#codetext')` and getting the first one.

Comment: @mrlew exactly! the second and third form also have same id as i want to use same html. each form should validate using same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, you can't have more than one element with the same `id`. It's against HTML specification and jQuery id selector only returns the first one (even if you have multiple).

As if you're using jQuery, I might suggest another approach to accomplish your goal.

First of all, get rid of the `codetext` `id`. Then, instead of using [*inline events*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_don't_use_these) (they are considered **bad practice**, as pointed in the MDN documentation), like you did, you can specify an event handler with jQuery using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Then, in the callback function, you can reference the form itself with `$(this)` and use the method [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to locate a child with the name `codetext`.

And, if you call [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), you cancel the form submission.

My suggestion:

**HTML form (can repeat as long as you want):**

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
  <input maxlength="5" name="codetext" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter here" /> 
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="SUMBIT" />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 //this way, you can create your forms dynamically (don't know if it's the case)    
 $(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {

    //find the input element of this form with name 'codetext'
    var inputCodeText = $(this).find("input[name='codetext']");

    if(inputCodeText.val().length != 5) {
        alert('Invalid Entry');
        e.preventDefault(); //cancel the default behavior (form submit)
        return; //exit the function
    } 

    //when reaches here, that's because all validation is fine
    showhidediv('div-info');

    //the form will be submited here, but if you don't want this never, just move e.preventDefault() from outside that condition to here; return false will do the trick, too

 });


});
```

#### Working demo: **https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/8kb9rzvv/**

Comment: This is really perfect solution for this problem. I am using same html and all forms are now validating fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem, that you will have multiple id `codetext`.
You need to change your code like that:

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">

<input maxlength="5" name="codetext" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter here" /> 

<input class="button" type="submit" value="SUMBIT" />
</form>
<form action="post.php" method="POST">

<input  maxlength="5" name="codetext" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter here" /> 

<input class="button" type="submit" value="SUMBIT" />
</form>
```

And your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var codecheck = $(this).find('input[name=codetext]').val();
        if(codecheck.length != 5)
        {
            alert('Invalid Entry');
        } else {
            showhidediv('div-info');
        }
        return false;   
    })
    })
```